# XCode - I cannot seem to remove files from a project

Tags: xcode

When i highlight a file and choose Edit->delete nothing happens.

What is going on. This is in the XCode IDE for Max OS

Comment: Very difficult to diagnose this problem.  Have you tried switching everything off and back on again ?  Sometimes Xcode seems to get its knickers in a twist temporarily so switching off and on is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking (two fingers, or cmd click) the file and selecting delete. It may be that edit>delete only works for code editing.